# Forcing a function to return NULL instead of it's predetermined return_type

Tags: c, null, return

Below is a command parsing function. It splits user input at the **"-"**.

If **"time-10"** is passed in, **10** is returned.
If no **"-"** is found I want to return **NULL** so I know that no **"-"** was found and the program can make decisions passed on that information.
However, because the function return type is **char** I have to return a **char pointer,** and am currently satisfying this requirement by returning the original argument.

Is there a way around this, or do I HAVE to return a Char pointer and write code that determines if that return value equates to, **'no - found'**?

```
char * second_arg(char * arg) {  
    char * j = strchr(arg, '-');
    if(j==NULL) {
        return arg;
    }
    return ++j;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function return type is not `char`; it is `char *`.
Since the function already returns a pointer to `char`, it is very easy to return NULL.

Just change the line `return arg;` to say `return NULL;`

Comment: This causes a segmentation fault

Comment: @seamus if there's a segmentation fault, I think it is almost certainly because of what the calling code does with the returned value, rather than with the contents of this function. You may want to spend time debugging the code, using a test string that does not contain a `'-'`

Comment: You are right. Problem was with the calling code handling the NULL being returned

Comment: @seamus `NULL` is intended to be used for pointers. You could also use `0` instead (which is usually what `NULL` is defined as), but writing `NULL` is preferred because it increases code clarity.

Comment: @seamus NULL is a pointer value. But it doesn't point to anything. If you try to access the thing that NULL points to, you get a segfault. Usually, people use NULL as a special value that means it's not pointing to anything.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Randall posted the right answer. A little code-golf oriented solution could also be:

```
char * second_arg(char * arg) {  
    char * j = strchr(arg, '-');
    return j?++j:j;
}
```

If j is `NULL`, it's also `false` in C. `++j` increments the variable *before* the evaluation of the line (I suggest to add comments to this code :)).